# Why unable to pass List<string> from static method to non-static method C#

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a static method like this:

```
private static void UpdateExportDate(List<string> lstWithdraw, List<string> lstUnit)
    {
        ServiceReference3.PSSWebServiceSoapClient pwssc = new ServiceReference3.PSSWebServiceSoapClient("PSSWebServiceSoap12");
        ((IContextChannel)pwssc.InnerChannel).OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0);

        pwssc.UpdateInfo(lstWithdraw, lstUnit);
    }
```

In another class, I have a non static method like this:

```
public void UpdateInfo(List<string> lstWithdraw, List<string> lstUnit)
    {
        UvAccountConversion uac = new UvAccountConversion();           
    }
```

When I run the project, it has an error stated that:

```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string[]'
```

I have tried to remove the List (which means I only pass 2 strings) and it is successful. However, I want to pass the records as '**List**'.

Please help!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the current code, did you miss anything to include? which line shows the actual error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try `List.ToArray()`

```
pwssc.UpdateInfo(lstWithdraw.ToArray(), lstUnit.ToArray());
```

Comment: Did you noticed the signature of `pwssc.UpdateInfo` ?

Comment: This will produce error: "Cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Appreciate the dedication of the upvoter, Hope that this will not be a sock puppet

Comment: How did this answer the question? As the question is currently put this is wrong. The OP needs to fix the question.

Answer (score 3):

The error message itself is "cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'string[]'" there is no difference between static and instance methods in terms of parsing parameters.

The error indicates that somewhere you need to have an array instead of a List

A list is not the same as an array, although you can call a method on the list to return an array.

```
List<string> someList = new List<string>{"a","B","c"};
someList.ToArray(); //string[] containing ["a","B","c"]
```

Comment: How it answers the question? Probably this will be a comment

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The error message itself is "cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string[]'" there is no difference between static and instance methods in terms of parsing parameters. The error indicates that *somewhere* they need to have an array instead of a List<string>

Comment: @MattiPrice - Your comment is precisely what you should have written in the answer. I would suggest you copy and paste it in. Then I think this would be the best answer.

Comment: Edited it in to be more explicit.

Comment: @MattiPrice Looks much better. I hope the OP comes along and changes the accepted answer.